# Oracle Index Clustering Factor

Tags: oracle, index, performance-tuning

My question is about Clustering Factor (CF) of Indexes in oracle

I have created a table as follows :

```
 Create table T2 as select  c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6 from T1 order by c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6;
 Create Index IDX on T2 ( c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6 )
 exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats ( user, 'T2' )

 select BLOCKS from user_tables where table_name = 'T2'
 --> 7543

 select clustering_factor from user_indexes where index_name = 'IDX'
 --> 15,073
```

As you can see - the CF of index is more than BLOCKS

Since the table was created with the rows ordered by c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6 and the index also was created in same order, should'nt the Clustering Factor for the index be close to the number of BLOCKS ?

Comment: You should add the full definition of `T1`, as data types likely explain what you see. How many rows are in those tables? Also, why blocks are in ALL CAPS?

Comment: The tables have 1 million rows. DDL of T1 ( c1 : vc2(10), c2 : number(30), c3 number(30), c4 vc2(80), c5 vc2(10), c6 vc2 (160).  BLOCKS and CF are in ALL CAPS to denote that the fields are in data dictionary

Comment: Please edit your question with the new information, don't leave it in comments.